# Matching UTF Characters with preg_match in PHP: (*UTF8) Works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a simple regular expression to check a username:

```
preg_match('/(*UTF8)^[[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]]|[ _.-])+$/i', $username);
```

In local testing (Windows 7 using WAMP), this will allow for usernames using UTF characters (such as é or ñ). However, when I move to test this on the server where the site will actually be hosted, I get the following warning:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: (*VERB) not recognized at offset 5 in /home/sites/vgmusic.com/test/Core/Impl/FormElementValidator.php on line 12

I have also tried this on a local Ubuntu installation and get the same error. In fact, I've only seen this work on my local development environment. Is there a way to allow for special characters that will work for all operating systems?

Comment: What do you expect that `(*UTF8)` does?

Comment: Well, before adding it, the above would return false when a character such as é was entered. After adding it, those characters were accepted and the above returned true. I was expecting it to allow said characters.

Comment: This is almost certainly down to PHP versions. Which PHP versions are you running? Do the phpinfo() pages contain any info on PCRE versions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try it by describing the characters by its [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
preg_match('/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u', $username)
```

Comment: Looks good. I believe the following will also allow for numbers as the original example had:
`preg_match('/^(\p{L}|\p{N})[(\p{L}|\p{N}) _.-]+$/u', $username)`

Comment: @S. DePouw, make that `'/^[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N} _.-]+$/u'`. Inside a character class, `(`, `)` and `|` just match `(`, `)` and `|`.

Answer (score 4):

I had already been trying with the `/u` parameter mentioned. On windows (PHP 5.2.16), adding the `/u` parameter worked fine for capturing a string containing unicode characters, however on CentOS 5 and PHP 5.2.16 i could still not capture a string containing unicode characters, using `.*` (preg_match basically failed to capture).

After a long time getting nowhere, messing around with the 'LOCALE' settings which changed nothing, i finally found [this site](http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/).

I did an `rpm -Uvh` of the appropriate version rpm provided, restarted apache, and suddenly my regexes worked great!

Even though I had UTF-8 support initially, my regexes were not capturing unicode strings until I installed the updated rpm, which also adds "Unicode properties support". I thought having UTF-8 support would have been enough, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

it seems it is an old post but as it is always a subject of interest I will post what I discovered [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). It is a small difference but makes code more simple. The thing is that **curly brackets are optional**.

The above code of Gumbo and Scott can be written more simple like this if someone wants to allow only letters (Unicode & non-Unicode) and blank spaces:

```
preg_match("/^\pL[\pL ]+$/u",$string)
```

I also noticed that preg_match accepts even more simple code as the following :

```
preg_match("/^[\pL ]+$/u",$string)
```