# Is it safe to use preg_ functions with ascii-character pattern and utf-8 multibyte subject?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know that if I use multibyte(UTF-8) characters for the pattern, I have to use `mb_` functions or have to use `u` option for pattern of `preg_` functions.

But when I use multibyte(UTF-8) characters only for the subject of `preg_` functions and use only ascii characters for the pattern, do `preg_` functions (without `u` option) work correctly?

I know that in this case I have to use `mb_` function or add `u` option to the pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace("/$utf8_multibyte_pattern/", '', $str);
```

I want to know if this code(`u` option is not used) is safe or not:

```
$ascii_pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9'$#\\\"%&()\-~|~=!@`{}[]:;+*/.,_<>?_\n\t\r]";
$multibyte_str = preg_replace("/$ascii_pattern/", '', $utf8_multibyte_str);
```

Comment: yes if you're using `/u` (unicode property) at the end. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351649/matching-utf-characters-with-preg-match-in-php-utf8-works-on-windows-but-not).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found the answer by myself.

**But someone who knows about character code well, please comment to this answer or post another answer.**

According to wikipedia, UTF-8 character codes don't contain ascii code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages

> The ASCII characters are represented by themselves as single bytes that do not appear anywhere else, which makes UTF-8 work with the majority of existing APIs that take bytes strings but only treat a small number of ASCII codes specially. This removes the need to write a new Unicode version of every API, and makes it much easier to convert existing systems to UTF-8 than any other Unicode encoding.

I think this means preg function with ascii pattern without u option is safe for multibyte(UTF8) subject.

And this code (without u option)

```
$multibyte_str = preg_replace("/$ascii_pattern/", '', $utf8_multibyte_str);
```

and this code (with u option)

```
$multibyte_str = preg_replace("/$ascii_pattern/u", '', $utf8_multibyte_str);
```

are the same.
Both correctly works.

Am I correct?

Comment: It's absolutely correct. In UTF-8, multibyte characters don't use the bytes of the ascii range `[\x00-\x7f]`. In this case using the u modifier is useless. That said, be careful when you use a shorthand character class like `\d` or `\w` since it doesn't contain the same character with and without the u modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe as far as I know as long as you use the unicode property (`/u`) like so:

```
$ascii_pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9'$#\\\"%&()\-~|~=!@`{}[]:;+*/.,_<>?_\n\t\r]";
$multibyte_str = preg_replace("/$ascii_pattern/u", '', $utf8_multibyte_str);
```

To see more information on unicode characters, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: thanks. but i know it is safe if i use /u. the question is whether it is safe or not if i do NOT use /u and do NOT use multibyte string in pattern(1st argument) but use multibyte string for subject(3rd argument).