# Php preg_match for multiple language

Tags: php

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/i", $name);
```

I have an input for **name**, I use preg_match to check, if user type number or symbol etc.

However this is only for English, how can I make it for multiple language? (ex. chinese, japanese etc.)

Comment: You're looking for a preg_match for multiple alphabets rather than languages...

Comment: Why do you even want to `preg_match` a name? Why not just check if there is anything in the input?

Comment: Therefore, this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351649/matching-utf-characters-with-preg-match-in-php-utf8-works-on-windows-but-not

Comment: You can use `preg_match('/^[\p{L} ]+$/u', $name);` (see: [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), scroll down to _Unicode character properties_)

Comment: wow, thx a lot!, can u post on answer, so i can close it