# preg_match() returns 0 although regex testers work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate a string using `/[\p{L}\s]{6,}/` and trying to match characters only (Unicode ones as well). I used [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test my regex and it works for the string `Владимир Алексић`. 
However, when I use that regex in `preg_match()` with the same string, it always returns `0`. Yet, it returns 1 if I avoid all characters except `A-Za-z`.

Why is that so?

[image: Proof for regex101]

Comment: preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351649/matching-utf-characters-with-preg-match-in-php-utf8-works-on-windows-but-not

Comment: @Jonathan But the pattern should match given subject and return 1. I used the same regex on regex101 and in my code, and the same string, but results are different.

Comment: Is regex101 using preg_match? I guess not

Comment: @Jonathan That one worked actually

Comment: The link supplied?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, and I've just seen that my regex wouldn't work because I didn't add u pattern modifier, which I didn't know I had to add. All good now, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome- pity I didn't add an answer -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\p` and other [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) which work with unicode character properties don't work unless the `u` [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is set.

```
/[\p{L}\s]{6,}/u
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Regex is really my weakness. Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use \p{Cyrillic} to match the cyrillic characters, i.e.:

```
/[\p{L}\p{Cyrillic}\s]{6,}/u
```

Source: [Source](http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/08/validating-cyrillic-utf8-alphanumeric.html)